# jQuery - declaration of a variable inside function halts parsing

Tags: javascript, jquery, web

I'm encountering an error I can't figure out. Declaring a variable within a function is causing the rest of the script to not execute. Take the working example below:

http://jsfiddle.net/nkcokmaq/1/

However, if I add:

```
var square_size = $('#grid_container').width()/input - 2;
```

Under:

```
var makeGrid = function(opt){
    if (opt >= 1 && opt <= 128){
        ...
```

The conditional if statement under the function makeGrid will not execute (but the else statement still will) - as in the jsfiddle below:

http://jsfiddle.net/nkcokmaq/2/

Any pointers?

Comment: `$('#grid_container').width()/input - 2;` From this, where is that `input` coming from..?

Comment: input isn't defined, and your linked non-working fiddle doesn't include jQuery but tried to use. Console ftw.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Here](http://jsfiddle.net/pyL0exrt/) is your working first example. There were js errors which prevent it's executing.

remove onclick handlers from your buttons

```
<button id="b1">Black</button>
<button id="b2">Multicoloured</button>
```

Add jquery link and add click handling.

```
$("#b1").click(function(e){clickButton(1)});
$("#b2").click(function(e){clickButton(2)});
```

Same with second fiddle. Add jq support, define your `input` variable in `makeGrid` function.

Answer (score 0):

Variable `input` isn't defined. You can either assign a value to `input`, such as:

```
   var input = 1;
```

Or use another variable for your calculation, such as `opt`:

```
   var square_size = $('#gridContainer').width() / opt - 2;
```

http://jsfiddle.net/nkcokmaq/3/